# Make constant a string generated from a function in F#

Tags: f#

I am new to F# and I have been pulling my hair out from this question:

The SqlCommandProvider requires a constant string which I am unable to provide by the below function.
Running it in F# interactive returns "This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value. "

```
let textgen (RIC: string, price: float, volume: int, inst: int, time:string) =
    let mutable mystring = "INSERT INTO hsbc(RIC, price, volume, type, time) VALUES (st1, st2, st3, st4, st5)"
    mystring <- mystring.Replace ("st1", RIC)
    mystring <- mystring.Replace ("st2", price.ToString())
    mystring <- mystring.Replace ("st3", volume.ToString())
    mystring <- mystring.Replace ("st4", inst.ToString())
    mystring <- mystring.Replace ("st5", time)
    mystring


let sqlcommand1 = textgen("0005.hk",71.2,5000,1,"2019-07-18 10:34:09.193")

type writedata4=SqlCommandProvider<sqlcommand1,connStr>
do
    let cmd6 = new writedata4(connStr)
    cmd6.Execute()
    0
```

I have done some research and know that this is a problem with sqlcommand1 not being a constant during compile time.  So I tried this:

```
[<Literal>]
let sqlcommand1 = textgen("0005.hk",71.2,5000,1,"2019-07-18 10:34:09.193")
```

which again returns: "This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value"

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

Update:
thanks!  I adapted the code from @Mark Pattison and this works:

```
let mywrite(RIC: string, price: float, volume: int, inst: int, time:string) =
    use cmd99 = new SqlCommandProvider<"INSERT INTO hsbc(RIC, price, volume, type, time) VALUES (@st1, @st2, @st3, @st4, @st5)", connStr>(connStr)
    cmd99.Execute(st1=RIC,st2=price,st3=volume,st4=inst,st5=System.DateTime.Parse time)
    |> ignore
```

however, the official docs does mention:

```
let cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<const(SqlFile<"GetDate.sql">.Text), connStr>(connStr)
cmd.Execute() |> ignore
```

Since the command is loaded from an external text, there should be even less compile time certainty and shouldn't work (but it appears to work).
Can you please tell me why? Thanks

Comment: Regarding your added question: The `SqlCommandProvider` is a type provider, which needs to know about the command (constant string or `.sql` file) at compile time to generate the correct types.  It won't work if you change the contents of the `.sql` file at run time.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I will investigate this further.  This is all very new coming from (elementary) python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is that the command text is a compile-time constant.  Clearly your `sqlcommand1` can't be, as it's created at runtime by calling `textgen`.

Here's an example of how to create a parametrised command using `@`, from the [docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/):

```
open FSharp.Data

[<Literal>]
let connectionString = 
    @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=True"

do
    use cmd = new SqlCommandProvider<"
        SELECT TOP(@topN) FirstName, LastName, SalesYTD 
        FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
        WHERE CountryRegionName = @regionName AND SalesYTD > @salesMoreThan 
        ORDER BY SalesYTD
        " , connectionString>(connectionString)

    cmd.Execute(topN = 3L, regionName = "United States", salesMoreThan = 1000000M) |> printfn "%A"

//output
//seq
//    [("Pamela", "Ansman-Wolfe", 1352577.1325M);
//     ("David", "Campbell", 1573012.9383M);
//     ("Tete", "Mensa-Annan", 1576562.1966M)]
```

You can see that the command string itself (starting `SELECT...`) is a constant string.

Comment: Just a side note: If there is a desire to "inject" e.g. a table name or field name or whatever it is, defined elsewhere, into the query string, that is possible, provided it is an F# literal. Just use the plus operator for this, so that it becomes part of the compile time constant string for the query. But I certainly don't recommend this practice in general, because it makes reading and editing the SQL difficult. Better then to just search and replace names and stuff in queries whenever needed.